# SessionHandlerInterface write method alternatives

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm using the following write method for the **SessionHandlerInterface class**:

```
public function write($session_id, $session_data) {
    $sth = DBCxn::get()->prepare("UPDATE sessions SET session_data = ?, last_update = NOW() WHERE session_id = ?");
    $sth->execute(array($session_data, $session_id));
    if ($sth->rowCount() == 0) {
        $sth = DBCxn::get()->prepare("INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, session_data, last_update) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
        $sth->execute(array($session_id, $session_data));           
    }
```

The problem is that if `session_data` for the update query does not change `rowCount()` will return 0, and in turn the function will try to insert a `session_id` that already exists and return an error.

I thought as a solution to do a select query to verify whether the `session_id` exists or not.

What other alternatives could be used to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read()` is called before `write()` (at the start of the session), and you'd have a `SELECT` query in there.

Therefore, you already know if you should do an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` - just use a property as a "row exists" flag, which you'd set from inside `read()` and you can later check for that in `write()`.